# Perceptron learning rule doesn't work

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, neural-networks

i'm a little bit lost ... can you help me ?

So I have this table of date (each row give a point with its group)

[image: data table]

[image]

So i took a random weight let's say : [1, -2]
H = 1 if n =< 0
    0 otherwise

a= H([1,-2][6,3]) = H(0) = 1 but the target output is 0 ... so we have to update the weight:
w -> w - p = [5 , -5] .
Next :

a= H([5,-5][3,3]= H(0)=1 the problem is : there the target output is 1 so we don't have to update the weight , but that's strange because the [5 -5] vector doesn't draw a linear separation between the 2 groups ...

Thanks for your help ? :)

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're mixing up the weight vector $w$ and the actual hyperplane defining the decision boundary. The way to interpret $w$ is as a vector which is orthogonal to any vector lying on the hyperplane. See [these slides](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/8-9-slides.pdf) for some visualization.

As you've said, the decision is defined by $1$ if $w_1 x + w_2 y > 0$ and $0$ otherwise. So to find the actual hyperplane (decision boundary) we can just solve for the place where the decision changes, which is at $0$. Using your $w$ we have 
$$
\begin{align*}
w_1 x + w_2 y &= 0\\
\implies 5 x + -5y &= 0\\
\implies x &= y.
\end{align*}
$$
So the decision boundary is given by the line $y = x$. Plotting this with your points we see that this $w$ does indeed define a separating hyperplane.

[image: linear decision boundary]

Answer (score 1):

If you're confused by the algorithm, the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) on Perceptron has some easy to understand Python code and an example to help guide you through calculations.